# Custom Credential Provider not loading

Tags: credential-providers

I am creating a custom credential provider for my university computer center.

The platform supported is Win 7.

I have tested it on few PCs. It is working fine on most of them, however for some PCs credential provider dll is not loading. All the registry entries are present.

Please suggest a solution. I have been stuck for weeks on this.

Comment: does it works? you can refers to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69986001/16980671). It said that make sure the target pc has Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistribute

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your DLL matches the platform that it is running on (i.e. x64) and make sure you can load any dependency DLLs.  If you have any exceptions in your credential provider that aren't handled appropriately (for instance in a constructor) then your provider won't load.