# Windows credential provider not shown in 21H1

Tags: windows, windows-10, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

--- UPDATE---

--- This post is possibly a duplicate one since my account StackOverflow is somehow restarted today ---

I already post this question as https://superuser.com/questions/1662866/windows-credential-provider-not-shown-in-21h1

But The only reply that I have is

> sounds more like a Stack Overflow question at this point

I already make sure that all DLL is well prepared [Custom Credential Provider not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157780/custom-credential-provider-not-loading)

Also I already make sure that all registry is also set https://www.thewindowsclub.com/custom-credential-providers-fails-to-load

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out we need the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistribute to work.

Thanks to [swiversecure](https://kb.swivelsecure.com/w/index.php/Windows_Credential_Provider)

> Important: the Credential Provider requires Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistributable to work. Recent operating systems already include this, but it will need to be installed on older operating systems if it has not already been installed. You can retrieve it from here. If you have already installed the credential provider, it is not necessary to uninstall it before installing the redistributable.

I don't know what is the reason why in version 21H1, that package is not included. Therefore, I have to download it first [using this link](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe). It is not necessary to restart the pc or reinstall the Credential provider, so I just lock my pc to see result. Then, my custom credential provider just showed up ._.